# How to auto-swipe as user types React Native TextInput Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am trying to implement a carousel using `Flatlist` or `ScrollView` (i tried both). The Carousel is compound of `TextInputs`.

What I wanna accomplish is the following:

```
There are 4 TextInputs.
when user type 6 digits on the first input, it automatically scrolls to the second and auto-focus the second input.
when the user type 6 digits on the second, it automatically scrolls to the third and auto-focus the third input.
etc...

the user must be enable to swipe back and change the TextInputs without being focused on other input as he types in something.
```

I already tried a switch case on the `onScroll` event of `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use [Flatlist's scrollToItem](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoitem) or [scrollToOffset](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoitem) method and [TextInput's focus method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#focus), and then listen to each text input as it changes.

```
...

handleInput = (event) => {    
  // calculate next position based on input text
  const nextPosition = this.getNextPosition(event);
  this.scrollViewRef.scrollToItem(nextPosition);

  /** 
  * or if you can calculate the exact next pixel offset for the desired 
  * item based on its dimensions:  
  * 
  * this.scrollViewRef.scrollToOffset(nextPosition);
  **/


  const { name } = event.target.dataset;
  const { text } = event.target;

  if (name === 'textInput1' && text.length === 6) {
    this.textInput2Ref.focus();
  } else if (name === 'textInput2' && text.length === 6) {
    this.textInput3Ref.focus();
  } else if (/*...*/) {
    /*...*/
  }
}

...

render() {
  <View>
    <TextInput 
        data-name={'textInput1'}
        ref={(ref) => this.textInput1Ref = ref} 
        onChange={this.handleInput}
    />
    <TextInput 
        data-name={'textInput2'}
        ref={(ref) => this.textInput2Ref = ref} 
        onChange={this.handleInput}
    />
    {/*...TextInput3, 4, etc.*/}
    <FlatList ref={(ref) => this.scrollViewRef = ref}/>
  </View>
}
```